# odata routing not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

This is my first OData application with asp.net MVC and i am not able to make it work. I need to return a single `Summary` object from the `SummaryController`, but facing an issue.

routing configuration -

```
public static IEdmModel CreateEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.EntitySet<Summary>("Summary");
    return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}

public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapODataRoute("OData", "odata", CreateEdmModel());
    config.EnableQuerySupport();    
    config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
}
```

controller and action method -

```
public class SummaryController : ODataController
{
        public Summary Get()
        {
             //....
             return someObj;
        }
}
```

The route that does not work -

```
/odata/Summary
```

Can anyone please help me understand how can i make the routing work?

Comment: What you done looks good to me. I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the model, you have setup Summary to be an EntitySet, this would return a collection of Summary objects. If you want that URL to always return one object then you need a Singleton.

The CreateEdmModel method should look like this:

```
public static IEdmModel CreateEdmModel()
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.Singleton<Summary>("Summary");
    return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```